# Why is my memory running out when file gets to big?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, cryptography

So the error I am getting is this.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll

I have never encountered this error before and I've looked it up on Google.
I do have a 64-Bit system.
I do have 16GB of RAM.
Some people said that I need to set the platform target to x64 in my project properties but wont that make it so only 64-bit systems will be able to run this application?

```
public static string RC4(string input, string key)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int x, y, j = 0;
    int[] box = new int[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        box[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        j = (key[i % key.Length] + box[i] + j) % 256;
        x = box[i];
        box[i] = box[j];
        box[j] = x;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        y = i % 256;
        j = (box[y] + j) % 256;
        x = box[y];
        box[y] = box[j];
        box[j] = x;

        result.Append((char)(input[i] ^ box[(box[y] + box[j]) % 256]));
    }
    return result.ToString(); //This would be the line throwing me the error.
}
```

Because every second im appending new text from a keyboard hook to a textfile. So lets say I type `abc` the first second its going to append that, now if I type `def` the next second its going to append that. This is all happening inside of a timer tick so its really straight forward.
Whenever the textfile reaches around 350 000KB it throws me that error.

Comment: Please share your piece of code where you write that input string to file

Comment: Do not use RC4 for production code, it has not been a secure encryption method for several decades. Use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to how big single objects are allowed to be, even on x64. The actual limit doesn't matter and depends on configuration, but the upshot is that when processing large volumes of data you should read through the data in pieces (usually via `Stream`), processing chunks at a time. Never try to hold the entire thing in memory at once. This applies equally to input and output.

Now, if you managed to load the entire thing into `input`, then you got lucky; but `StringBuilder` is intentionally *oversized*, so that it doesn't have to keep allocating all the time. You **might** be able to "fix" your code by telling `StringBuilder` the correct amount of characters you need in the constructor, but that is only a temporary hack that will let you to process slightly larger data. The *real* fix is to not attempt to process huge data in a single chunk.

Comment: I got a bit worried when using the RC4 algorithm, I instantly saw that it generated waaaay to much, Are there any other encryption methods you would recommend? Somethign simple and secure.

Comment: @JohnS.Washington RC4 is a stream cipher; used *correctly* (streaming, not all at once), it should be fine. The main reason not to use RC4 is because it has multiple known vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yeah I read about that aswell, anything else you would recommend that is more secure?

Comment: @JohnS.Washington I'm loathe to make positive security recommendations; only negative ones :)

Comment: I see, which one would be the least negative one in your opinion?

Comment: If you described your use case it will be easier to be specific but take a look at AES encryption.

Comment: @Equalsk Thank you.

Comment: @JohnS.Washington Keep in mind that simply using AES is not enough. You'll need to think about the mode of operation, padding mode, handling of the random initialization vector as well as adding a proper authentication tag (HMAC or a mode that already includes this like GCM). It's hard to get right and absolutely secure, but most encryption permits implementation in a streaming fashion (except two-pass modes). I'd suggest that you look for a library that has a streaming API *and* specifically supports the things I mentioned above.